# How to fit a png icon in the boundaries of a google map v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I want to use `map.fitBounds` to fit points on a google map. It works good, as soon as I use a taler icon for my point. my icon is 95px tall.

you can see how it looks like if I have 2 points in the map:

http://jsfiddle.net/EwQW5/4/

What I need is to calculate a point that is (95 px translated to decimal coordinates) north from the actual center of the marker `markerLatlng`, so that the whole icon is visible.

Any ideas on how to do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: You didn't call `bounds.extend()`. See [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/EwQW5/5/). What do you want to achieve? To set bounds so complete icon is visible?

Comment: You can do something similar to [this question: "Include open infowindows within bounds of map, when using fitbounds"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002001/include-open-infowindows-within-bounds-of-map-when-using-fitbounds/21012179#21012179), but use your icon height, rather than that of the infowindow.

Comment: @AntoJurković I did call `bounds.extend()` after every new marker. (see like 30 and 36 of my example). Yes, the idea is to have the icon visible.

Comment: @geocodezip I will try that out, thanks. I think this goes into the right direction.